# How to organize Procs in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, functional-programming

Translating a script from OOP to FP, I am trying to understand how to replace "bags of methods" (classes) with "bags of procs".  Procs are those composable (<<), anonymous micro-objects with Binding but I haven't seen an example using more than a couple of #call. My modest script has few tens of methods: replacing them with procs requires some kind of container for code organisation.

Tried to store Procs into hashes. But Hash is not designed with this application in mind.  As example, calling a proc from another proc inside the same hash is awkward.

Tried to store Procs into classes, associated to variables. But encapsulation reduces my capability to access outside variables (losing one key benefits of closures) and complicates access to procs (either with instance variables have to instantiate the class or with class variables have to create class accessor methods).

Tried to store Procs into methods but then where's the gain.

```rb
require 'net/http'
require 'json'
require 'iron_cache'
require 'discordrb'

class Config
      # config vars
end

data_space = {
    :message => ""
    }

bot = Discordrb::Bot.new(token: Config::DISCORD_TOKEN, ignore_bots: true)
channel = bot.channel(Config::DISCORD_CHANNEL_ID)
cache = IronCache::Client.new.cache("pa")

bot_control = {
    :start => proc {bot.run(:async)},
    :stop => proc do
        bot.stop
        exit(0)
    end,
    :send => proc {data_space[:message].then {|m| bot.send_message(channel, m)}},
    "messaging?" => proc do |wish|
        [ Config::MESSAGING[wish.first] , Config::NIGHTTIME_FLAG ].compact.first
    end
}

cache_control = {
    :get_flag => proc {|flag| cache.get(flag)&.value},
    :set_wish => proc do |wish, exp_sec|
        cache.put("messaging", wish.to_json, :expires_in => exp_sec)
        data_space[:message] << "#{wish.first} got it!"
    end,
    :exp_sec => proc do
        t = Time.now
        (t-Time.new(t.year,t.month,t.day,Config::EXP_REF,0,0)).to_i
    end,
    :get_wish => proc do
        msg = proc {cache_control[:get_flag].call("messaging")}
        msg ? JSON.parse(msg) : [nil, nil]
    end
}
```

```rb
bot_control[:start].call
data_space[:message] << "ah"
bot_control[:stop].call if (bot_control["messaging?"]<<cache_control[:get_wish]).call
(bot_control[:stop]<<bot_control[:send]).call
```

actually delivers.

But isn't the kind of code I consider readable. Or an improvement over OOP.
Please advise.

---

### Edit

Looks like my attempt with a Hash to group procs was in the right direction. As described [elsewhere](https://medium.com/@baweaver/functional-programming-in-ruby-closures-ac80547eb40d) a hash within a Proc adds instance methods as #count, #keys and #store to access and manipulate it. Therefore I can write something like:

```rb
bc = proc { |args|
  {
    start: proc {...},
    stop: proc {...}
  }
}

bot_control = bc.call
bot_control[:start].call
bot_control[:stop].call
```

With some caveats. Values returned by the hash are procs and composition methods (<< and >>) are added but they don’t work. Also I haven’t found how to reference other values from within the hash. Though it’s possible to add methods (private by default but can be declared public) and reference them from within values.

So I obtained nested closures (variables leak in all the way down) but code at this point isn’t much different from a regular class. #new has become #call (Proc inherit from Method after all) but with not much improvement in FP direction. Please advise.

Comment: Why don't you just use class methods (like 'static' methods in other languages)?

Comment: @maxpleaner I think OP wants the functions to have a function composition operator, which Ruby's methods don't cleanly support

Comment: You probably want to use the more minimal JavaScript-style hash declarations: `{ start: ... }` instead of `{ :start => ... }` as that's been around since Ruby 1.9 and is fully supported now. The old 1.8 style is only necessary when using things like string keys.

Comment: I wrote an answer here on going back from "FP" to OOP because I'm not sure what the goal is here. This isn't functional programming, it's just a "bag of functions" as you say. "Functional programming" generally refers to functions that always produce the same output for any given set of arguments, that is *they are state-free*. Using a closure to encapsulate state completely destroys that. The style you have here isn't "functional", but it sure is heavily JavaScript flavoured.

Comment: @tadman definitely agree that this isn't functional, but it's close and not that hard to fix.

Comment: @Max Honestly, it's nowhere near close. If you'd look at how you'd solve this problem in a functional programming language like Erlang it would look totally different.

Comment: @tadman I understand the fundamental issue with “message” but apart from that don’t see what else breaks the FP paradigm. Also you missed the core question: how to organize tens or more of closures in Ruby w/o encapsulation emptying the effect of binding.

Comment: I think Ruby is a really bad language to experiment with this form of programming as Ruby's functional programming comes across much differently. Try this in Erlang or Haskell, languages which force you to think in terms of functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use modules and constants.

```
module BotControl
  Start = proc {bot.run(:async)}
  Stop = proc do
      bot.stop
      exit(0)
  end
  Send = proc {DataSpace::Message.then {|m| bot.send_message(channel, m)}}
  Messaging = proc do |wish|
      [ Config::MESSAGING[wish.first] , Config::NIGHTTIME_FLAG ].compact.first
  end
end
```

Note that this code won't work as-is: the `bot` variable is not visible! There are a couple approaches to fixing that, but they're beyond the scope of this question (my 2¢, it should be a parameter to those functions).

Usage would look like

```
(BotControl::Messaging<<CacheControl::GetWish).call
```

Your functions should be constants, so this protects you from reassignment (which a hash wouldn't). Also modules can't be instantiated/inherited so this avoids any kind of OOPness. Another benefit is that modules can be included, so if you have a context where you want some functions to be top-level, you can easily do that.

---

### Edit

You might be tempted to do this using anonymous modules e.g.

```
BotControl = Module.new do
  Start = proc {bot.run(:async)}
  ...
end
```

But that won't work because the scope of constants in Ruby is *lexical* i.e. it matters what module they're inside at the *parsing* stage, not at runtime. In the above example, at the parser level, `Start` is simply at top-level, because it is not inside any module (`Module.new` is just a method call, which is evaluated at runtime). So this approach doesn't actually group anything together.

Comment: To make this properly functional you'd have to give everything as an argument, things like `bot` can't magically appear. I'm not sure what benefits, if any, this style of programming has.

Comment: @Max the anonymous style doesn't work:  ```BotControl = Module.new do    Start = proc {bot.run(:async)}  end  BotControl::Start.call  ```  returns ```uninitialized constant BotControl::Start (NameError)``` : why?

Comment: @WuMing2 The example I'd give wouldn't use procs because that's not how Ruby works. The "When in Rome" principle applies here. Do it the Ruby way in Ruby. If you want to explore functional programming, that's a great learning experience, but Ruby's not the best place to do that. Erlang and by extension Elixir, which is very Ruby inspired and runs in the Erlang VM, are two great places to go for that.

Comment: @tadman it will be interesting to see a solution in a different language (e.g. Julia). I.e. how you group functions and at the same time leverage closures-ness without encapsulation.

Comment: @WuMing2 edited to clarify why `Module.new` doesn't work

Comment: @Max edited my question with the hash form. Interesting, what do you think? I haven’t found references of it in rdoc.  Also a Costant in main() isn’t automatically global?

Comment: @WuMing2 tadman is right that Ruby is not designed to support FP. _Any_ approach you decide to take is going to have weird issues. I like the module approach because it leverages more of the language and reflects more of a pure functional style. You seem to want a pseudo-functional style where you have closures capturing variables a la javascript. I'm not a big fan of that paradigm, so I don't have any suggestions of how to do it in a good way.

Comment: Max and @tadman thanks to both of you. It was nice and useful not to mumble about it on my own.

Comment: One follow up question. Closures embed variables outside the block scope. You disagree about using the “captured” variables or I misunderstood the closure concept? I am not familiar with JavaScript, just trying to understand.

Comment: @WuMing2 Closures are useful and fine to use in certain contexts, but it looks like you want the entire structure of your program to be based on closures capturing certain local variables when they are created. That sounds like a huge anti-pattern and a headache to maintain.

Comment: Thought release from encapsulation and composition capabilities were closures main reason to exist. What’s the use case then?

Comment: @WuMing2 I see closures as more of a convenience feature: anything you do with a closure you could do explicitly by encapsulating whatever local scope you need in a proper object and then calling a method on that object. But there's no real benefit to that, so it's nicer to use closures. Just because a language feature exists doesn't mean you _have_ to use that feature as much as possible and rely on it for your entire program's structure. Note that _every block in Ruby in a closure_! Most blocks should not be capturing local variables!